# Modify HTMl on header.php on Block Theme like Twenty Twenty Three?

Tags: theme-development, themes, block-editor

I'm trying to hide the WordPress version without using any plugin.
Many pages suggest doing this using `functions.php` with the following code:

```php
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

Or

```php
function remove_wordpress_version() {
return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator', 'remove_wordpress_version');
```

But Twenty Twenty Three has no `functions.php`. And when I create it with these lines, it won't make any difference.

As an alternative, I was trying to find the PHP file where the HTML structure for the page is defined. To remove this line:

```php
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 6.3.1" />
```

But I was not able to find it anywhere.
In fact, I was doing a file search for the string "generator" or even "meta" and I can't find it in any of its files.

Where is this defined?

How can I remove it or hide it?